# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dotenv (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on MAC and have created a new virtual environment for the project where i want to install the library - python-dotenv but getting below errors. To be noted that the python version on venv is Python 3.8.9. In this venv, i have 3 packages as of now -

```
pip        21.1.2
setuptools 57.0.0
wheel      0.36.2
```

Can someone please help with the below errors which i get after running the command pip install python-dotenv?

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dotenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-dotenv
```

Comment: Strange ... what happens if you manually download and install the wheel from PyPi? Would it work? As a workaround you can download the sources from the GitHub repo and install locally ...

Comment: @AmosEgel Could you please elaborate with some steps since i am not able to understand?

Comment: Sure. You could go to the [download section of PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#files) and download the wheel file. Then, you can install the wheel locally with `pip install python_dotenv-0.19.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. Does this work? Alternatively, you can clone the source code with `git clone https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv.git`, change directory to the folder that contains the setup.py and then install the package from source with `pip install .`  Please not that both suggestions are only workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users 'pip install python-dotenv' is what worked for me, not 'pip install dotenv'

Answer (score -1):

Try installing dotenv:

pip install dotenv